# Faster method to compare two columns from 2 different workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

So I have some code using for loops currently doing this and it takes roughly 6 minutes to run...

I have many sheets showing the same columns with some different data.
One column comes in either a named form or a numerical form (Depending on how a user input it to a completely separate database).

Another database contains 2 columns: one being the numerical form of data while the other is named.

My database currently compares my "name" column if numerical with the numerical column in this other database and when it finds a match it changes my "name" cell to match the corresponding name cell in the other database.

Is there any faster way to do this than using for loops?
I have to replicate the code around 12 times for different sheets to do the same task.

As previously stated, overall to run across all 12 its taking around 6 minutes

```
Sub 6mincode()

Workbooks("1").Activate

N = Workbooks("1").Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
N2 = Workbooks("2").Sheets("Data Sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

For I = 2 To N
    If (WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Sheets("Data").Cells(I, "B").Value)) = True Then
        For zz = 8 To N2
            If StrComp(Sheets("Data").Cells(I, "B").Value, Workbooks("2").Sheets("Data Sheet").Cells(zz, "B").Value) = 0 Then
                Workbooks("1").Sheets("Data").Cells(I, "B").Value = Workbooks("2").Sheets("Data Sheet").Cells(zz, "C").Value
            End If
         Next zz
    End If
Next I

End Sub
```

Comment: yes a faster way is to put everything into a table in a database

Comment: I'd love to do that however the databases come from various sources containing a wide range of differing information updating at various times in different ways. I can't just combine them all

Answer (score 1):

You can save the second loop and use `Application.Match` instead, it will save you a lot of time.

See code below, explanations inside the code's comments:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sixmincode()

Dim N As Long, N2 As Long, I As Long
Dim Rng As Range, MatchRow

With Workbooks("1").Sheets("Data")
    N = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
End With

With Workbooks("2").Sheets("Data Sheet")
    N2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row ' get last row with data in column B

    ' set the Range to Match with
    Set Rng = .Range("B8:B" & N2)
End With

With Workbooks("1").Sheets("Data")
    For I = 2 To N
        If IsNumeric(.Cells(I, "B").Value) Then ' use IsNumeric
            ' use Application.Match, if Not IsError means there is a match found in the second workbook
            If Not IsError(Application.Match(.Cells(I, "B").Value, Rng, 0)) Then
                MatchRow = Application.Match(.Cells(I, "B").Value, Rng, 0)
                .Cells(I, "B").Value = Workbooks("2").Sheets("Data Sheet").Cells(MatchRow, "C").Value
            End If
        End If
    Next I
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This makes my macro a lot smoother running and no longer takes 6minutes to do this one small part in a much bigger tool :)

Comment: @DaleSwire  if you could provide more data, maybe adding  a screenshot of both worksheets and your desired result

Comment: @DaleSwire the code searches for a match in column "B" (entire column) in  `Workbooks("2")`, if it finds a match it takes the data of column "C" (same row) and puts it in column "B". If there's no match, nothing happens, just continue. Isn't it what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: @DaleSwire add `Debug.Print MatchRow` inside the `If`, see what you are getting

Comment: Nothing comes up putting it in either If statement. Stepping through the code, it finds a numerical value, goes to "If Not IsError" then goes to End If